# Fuse two input-files with haskell conduit library

Tags: haskell, streaming, conduit

I'm trying to fuse two input files with `conduit`.

file1.dat:

```
META 1
META 2
META 3
TS 1
1
2
3
TS 2
3
4
5
```

file2.dat:

```
META 1
META 2
META 3
TS 1
0.1
0.0
0.3
TS 2
0.1
0.2
0.1
```

what I need is a function to source and fuse the input files, discard meta-data and merge on values in between `TS`-lines

```
sourceFiles :: FilePath -> FilePath -> ConduitM i (Double, Double) m ()
sourceFiles f1 f2 = undefined
```

Combination (e.g. `+,-,*`) would then look like

```
combine :: (Double -> Double-> Double) -> (Double, Double) -> Double
combine f (x,y) = f x y
```

I would be very grateful, if someone could give me a hint how to start with `sourceFiles`.

**EDIT**

As an output file of 'addition-combination' I would expect:

output.dat:

```
META 1 
META 2
META 3
TS 1
1.1
2.0
3.3
TS 2
3.1
4.2
5.1
```

Comment: SO doesn't use GitHub flavored Markdown. Please have a look at [the Markdown editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for future question/answer formatting

Comment: That being said, it's unclear how your files should get combined.

Comment: Could you give an example of the expected output?

Comment: Would you recommend the streaming library?